# inequality for a function

Tags: real-analysis

So, we have a function $f:\mathbb{R}-\{1\}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}, \:f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+2}{x-1}$ and we have to show that $f(x)-f(\frac{1}{x})\geq8,\:\forall\:x>1$. What I've done is this: $\forall\:x<1\:,f(x)\leq-1$ and $\forall\:x>1,f(x)\geq7$. So, if $x>1$ then $\frac{1}{x}<1$ and then we have $f(x)-f(\frac{1}{x})\geq8,\:\forall\:x>1$. Is this correct or is there something missing in the given data? I am thinking that if $x>1$ we have to look at the function $f$ only in the $(1,\infty)$. Or, my solution is correct because $\frac{1}{x}$ is making me look at the function $f$ when $x<1$? Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Note that the given inequality is 
$$f(x)-f(1/x)=\frac{(x+1)^3}{x(x-1)}\geq 8,$$
that is  for $x>1$,
$$h(x)=(x+1)^3-8x(x-1)\geq 0$$
which holds because $h(1)=8$ and $h$ is strictly increasing since $$h'(x)=3(x+1)^2-16x+8=3x^2-10x+11>0 \quad (\Delta=10^2-12\cdot 11<0).$$

Comment: yeah, this is what I've noticed in my last reply to Dr. Sonnard.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you have to prove that $$\frac{x^2+x+2}{x-1}-\frac{\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x}+2}{\frac{1}{x}-1}\geq 8$$ and this is equivalent to $$\frac{(x+1)^3}{x(x-1)}\geq 8$$

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at this too, but what u think about my solution?

Comment: You have to consider also the numerator.

Comment: You are wrong, it's $x^3-5x^2+11x+1$.But what if I keep 8 on the right side and on the left we have $\frac{(x-1)^3}{x(x-1)}\geq8$

Comment: Yes indeed it should be ${\frac {{x}^{3}+3{x}^{2}+3\,x+1}{x \left( x-1 \right) }}\geq 8$ according also to RobertZ solution.

Comment: Yes this was my mistake, corrected now!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is correct since for $x>1$

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+2}{x-1}\ge 7 \iff x^2-6x+9=(x-3)^2\ge 0$$

and for $x<1$

$$f(x)=\frac{x^2+x+2}{x-1}\le -1 \iff x^2+2x+1=(x+1)^2\ge 0$$

then for $x>1$ and $y=\frac1x<1$

$$f(x)-f\left(\frac1x\right)=f(x)-f(y)\ge 7+1=8$$

Comment: thx a lot gimusi for looking to my solution!

Comment: @Numbers I saw you were interested on that, also solution by RobertZ is very nice!